# Adding CustomEntity to the Plane Anchor in RealityKit

Tags: swift, realitykit

I have implemented a simple custom entity as shown below:

```
class Box: Entity, HasModel, HasAnchoring {
        
    required init(color: UIColor) {            
        super.init()                    
        self.components[ModelComponent.self] = ModelComponent(mesh: MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.3), 
                                                         materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: color, isMetallic: true)])
    }
    
    convenience init(color: UIColor, position: SIMD3<Float>) {
        self.init(color: color)
        self.position = position 
    }
    
    required init() {
        fatalError("init() has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

I try to add the Box entity to the anchor, defined by the horizontal plane.

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)            
    let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
        
    let box = Box(color: .red)
    anchorEntity.addChild(box)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchorEntity)
    return arView
}
```

But, the Box entity never appears to be resting on the horizontal plane. It always seems to be floating on the top. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent world anchoring at [0, 0, 0], you don't need to conform to the `HasAnchoring` protocol:

```
class Box: Entity, HasModel {
    // content...
}
```

So, your `AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)` are now active.

Comment: Thanks Andy! So When we conform to HasAnchoring what exactly it is doing? Is it asking the entity to anchor by itself yet not using the .plane AnchorEntity.

Comment: If the `Box` class conforms to the `HasAnchoring` protocol, then any object of the Box class "promises" to implement  `anchor.anchoring` with default type `AnchorEntity(world: [0,0,0])`. But the target may be any: `.image`, `.face`, `.camera`, etc (not only `.world`).

Comment: That is, you ordered your object to not only store the model, but also be the anchor. That blocked the `AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy! Really appreciate it.

Comment: I need to insert the HasAnchor protocol, in this case how do I solve the positioning described above? thank you 1000

Comment: Hi @WhiteTiger, ask a question with your source code.